# Explanation of 'gets' method: String being printed without any user input?

Tags: ruby, methods, file-io, user-input

I'm running through the Learn Ruby the Hard Way exercises, and have a question about the syntax in Exercise 20

```
input_file = ARGV.first

def print_all(f)
 puts f.read
end

def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0)
end

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count}, #{f.gets.chomp}"
end

current_file = open(input_file)

puts "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

in the "print_a_line" function, the argument "f" if string-interpolated, and the gets.chomp method is called on this argument. This is what appears on the console when the code is run (using a sample text file as ARGV.first, with three lines)

```
First let's print the whole file:
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
This is Line 3
Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:
1, This is Line 1
2, This is Line 2
3, This is Line 3
```

My question is this: why are we calling the gets.chomp on the "f" parameter? Where is the "gets" user input coming from? Why does this work, but justing using "f" without any attached methods doesn't print the lines from the text file? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets` actually has **nothing to do** with user input. Neither in this case, nor in the "usual" form you might be used to:

```
puts "what's your answer?"
answer = gets.chomp
```

In general, it is a method on IO objects which reads a string ("string" being defined as "all characters from current position up to (and including) a linebreak").

In your example it's being called on a `File` object (and, therefore, reads content from the opened file, line by line). The ["naked" form](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) reads lines from files, passed via command line arguments or (if no files were passed) from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29). Note that standard input is not necessarily read from the keyboard (which is what you'd call "user input"). Input data can be [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) into your program.

> but just using using "f" without any attached methods doesn't print the lines from the text file

`f` is a reference to a file object. It does not represent any useful printable content. But you can use it to read some content from the file, which you do (`f.gets`).

Comment: ok, deleted erroneous link. Great answer, cleared up the confusion I had as well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev just did- still getting used to these stackoverflow procedures...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Every line in the file are ended with a newline character (`"\n"`), the method `puts` displays the string and a newline so it would display the string and two new lines. The chomp method will remove the new line at the end of the string so only one newline will be displayed.

See the doc => https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp

Answer (score 0):

The `gets` you see there is not for user input. Rather it belongs to the IO class and reads the next line of an IO stream.
You can find this in Ruby doc 
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-gets

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your feedback